# How to remove duplicates by comparing two columns' values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
columnA  columnB   columnC
a          0         a
c          1        c|f
b          2        a|b|c
```

For such a dataframe, I want to change the columnC to:

```
columnA  columnB   columnC
    a          0         
    c          1        f
    b          2        a|c
```

for each element in columnC, I want to check whether it exists in the corresponding column A; if it exists, then drop it from colulmnC.

I want to write a function like:

```
df['columnC'] = df[['columnA', 'columnC']].apply(remove_duplicate)


def remove_duplicate(columnA, columnC):
    
    c_values = set(columnC.split('|'))

    if columnA in c_values.copy:
        c_values.remove(columnA)

    new_C = '|'.join(c_values)

    return c_values
```

But this complains:

```
TypeError: remove_duplicate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'columnC'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension could also work:

```
outcome = ["|".join([ent for ent in right if ent != left])
           for left, right in 
           zip(df.columnA, df.columnC.str.split("|"))
           ]

df.assign(columnC=outcome)

    columnA     columnB     columnC
0      a            0   
1      c            1          f
2      b            2         a|c
```

Note that `df.assign` does not make the result permanent. You can reassign to the original `df` or just do:

```
df['columnC'] = outcome
```

Comment: Did you test it? Why does my test still show duplicates exist in two columns?

Comment: yes i did test it. using your sample data

Comment: note the `df.assign` does not replace your existing df. you have to `df = df.assign` to make the change

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `explode`, `map` and `groupby.agg`

```
s = df['columnC'].str.split('|').explode().to_frame('columnC')
s1 = s.assign(columnA=s.index.map(df['columnA']))

df['columnC'] = s1.loc[s1['columnC'].ne(s1['columnA'])].groupby(level=0)['columnC'].agg('|'.join)

  columnA  columnB columnC
0       a        0     NaN
1       c        1       f
2       b        2     a|c
```

Comment: Can the NaN be replaced with empty string ''?

Comment: yep `df['columnC'].fillna('')` @marlon

Comment: I got a KeyError for the df['columnC'] line complaining columnA

Comment: hmm, might be that your index wasn't int based lke i assumed, can you post the full stack trace @marlon

Comment: @marlon looks like you missed the first two lines of code, make sure you include al the code above not just the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1=df[~df['columnC'].isin(df['columnA'])]#drop cross colum duplicates
df1=df1.assign(columnC=df1['columnC'].str.split('|'))#Convert c to list
df1['columnC']=df1. apply(lambda x: set(x['columnC'])-set(x['columnA']), axis=1)#Sets to eliminate values in column A from Column C
```

Comment: for the columnC, the resulting value should still be a string delimited by '|'. How to achieve that?

Comment: I thought it didnt matter. Please try `df1['columnC']=df1['columnC'].map(list).str.join('|')`

Comment: Unfortunately, I still received non-string values which produces error in later code.

Comment: Works for me. What version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `split('|')` then join it back with a single apply statement.

```
df['columnC'] = df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(i for i in x.columnC.split('|') if i != x.columnA) ,axis=1)
```

This should solve it

The output will be:

Before:

```
  columnA  columnB columnC
0       a        0       a
1       c        1     c|f
2       b        2   a|b|c
```

After:

```
  columnA  columnB columnC
0       a        0        
1       c        1       f
2       b        2     a|c
```